# Given two matrices and a function that takes two vectors, how to vectorize mean of function for every pair of vectors from the matrices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization

I am working on evaluating recommendation algorithms (on their ranking performance). Here, a row in the `true_scores` (binary) matrix is ground values for all items of a user while a row in the `predicted_scores` (continuous) matrix is predicted scores for all items from some algorithm. `sklearn` has the method `average_precision_score` which takes two arrays (true & predicted) returning the *score*. What's needed is mean of these *scores* across all users. (BTW `true_scores` & `predicted_scores` obviously have the same shape)

Currently, I am using `for` loop for *averaging* across users

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score as aps

def mean_aps(true_scores, predicted_scores):
    '''Mean Average Precision Score'''
    return np.mean([aps(t, p) for t, p in zip(true_scores, predicted_scores) if t.sum() > 0])
```

Can we eliminate the `for` loop in the code above and write it completely in numpy? I basically want to speed up this code (possibly using vectorization).

I understand we may need a custom implementation of the method `average_precision_score`. So I will reframe the question: I need a numpy-aware implementation of mean of scores for [any ranking score like *NDCG*](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/7337391).

Comment: [`average_precision_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) *does* support an additional sample dimension, i.e. 2d arrays.

Comment: @a_guest that is for multilabel classification. It won't work for this use-case.

Comment: Try [numba jit](http://numba.pydata.org/)

Comment: @Faboor: When I try it on this code, it seems this function / library isn't supported. I have tried it on other metrics like _NDCG_, there I am facing the issue that [iteration on ND-arrays isn't supported](https://www.google.com/search?q=numba+iterating+over+2D+array&oq=numba+iterating+over+2D+array&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i65l2j69i60l2.1512j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). When I try it by indexing, the performance seems to go worse rather than improve.

Comment: You may need a custom implementation of average precision, which is a bit tricky. What is the format of true scores and predicted scores? Are the matrices both binary? Or are they in the format that true_scores is binary and predicted_scores contains decision probabilities? Please give a small example of the inputs, for test purposes.

Comment: If true scores and predicted scores are both matrices with binary values, it's possible to rewrite the entire operation without any loops.

Comment: @Mercury: `true_scores` is binary while `predicted_scores` is continuous. I have updated the question.

Comment: @kamalbanga you should provide some test input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I've listed three implementations for the problem.

Firstly, it's possible to completely eliminate loops, but the resulting function `avg_prec_noloop()` is quite memory hungry as it tries to do *every* operation in one go. As long as the number of items is within 100, it'll always work pretty fast. Unfortunately, it consumes too much memory when the number of items tends towards 1000 or more, and will cause a crash. I'm including this just to show that it can be done without loops, but I don't recommend using it.

Following a similar logic to the original, but by adding a single loop over items, we have the function `avg_prec_colwise`. We can calculate precision and recall @K for all users by taking entire threshold columns at a time. It's has a similar time to the previous no loop implementation, but it isn't quite as memory hungry and still has that property that it's quite a bit faster when items<=100, irregardless of number of users. For 100,000 users and 10 items, it's nearly 300 times as fast as the original one; but if items>=1000, it becomes hundred times slower than the original. Whenever you have the scenario that you have a large number of users and a small number of items, I recommend you use this.

Lastly, I have an implementation `avg_prec_rowwise` that is possibly the closest to sklearn's one. It doesn't have the amazing gain of the colwise or the noloop functions when items are lower, but it is consistently 10-20% faster than using the original, no matter the number of items or users. For general purpose, I recommend you use this one.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score as aps
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve as prc
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def mean_aps(true_scores, predicted_scores):
    '''Mean Average Precision Score'''
    return np.mean([aps(t, p) for t, p in zip(true_scores, predicted_scores) if t.sum() > 0])

def avg_prec_noloop(yt, yp): 
    valid = yt.sum(axis=1) != 0
    yt, yp = yt[valid], yp[valid] 

    THRESH = np.sort(yp).T
    yp = yp.reshape(1, yp.shape[0], yp.shape[1]) >= THRESH.reshape(THRESH.shape[0], THRESH.shape[1], 1)

    a = (yt*(yt==yp)).sum(axis=2)
    b = yp.sum(axis=2)
    c = yt.sum(axis=1)

    p = (np.where(b==0,0,a/b))
    r = a/c
    rdif = np.vstack((r[:-1]-r[1:],r[-1]))

    return (rdif*p).sum()/yt.shape[0]

def avg_prec_colwise(yt, yp):
    valid = yt.sum(axis=1) != 0
    yt, yp = yt[valid], yp[valid] 
    N_USER, N_ITEM = yt.shape

    THRESH = np.sort(yp)
    p, r = np.zeros((N_USER, N_ITEM)), np.zeros((N_USER, N_ITEM))
    c = yt.sum(axis=1)

    for i in range(N_ITEM):
        ypt = yp >= THRESH[:,i].reshape(-1,1)
        a = (yt*(yt==ypt)).sum(axis=1)
        b = ypt.sum(axis=1)        
        p[:,i] = np.where(b==0,0,a/b).reshape(-1)
        r[:,i] = a/c

    rdif = np.hstack((r[:,:-1]-r[:,1:],r[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)))

    return (rdif*p).sum()/N_USER

def avg_prec_rowwise(yt, yp):
    valid = yt.sum(axis=1) != 0
    yt, yp = yt[valid], yp[valid] 
    N_USER, N_ITEM = yt.shape

    p, r = np.zeros((N_USER, N_ITEM)), np.zeros((N_USER, N_ITEM))
    for i in range(N_USER):
        a, b, _ = prc(yt[i,:], yp[i,:])
        p[i,:len(a)-1] = a[:-1]
        r[i,:len(b)-1] = b[:-1]
    rdif = np.hstack((r[:,:-1]-r[:,1:],r[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)))

    return (rdif*p).sum()/N_USER
```

Some time scenarios: 1)Really less items

```
N_USERS = 10000
N_ITEMS = 10
a = np.random.choice(2,(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
b = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    mean_aps(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Original:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_colwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Colwise:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_rowwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Rowwise:',end-start)
```

Out:

```
Original: 47.91176509857178
Colwise: 0.16370844841003418
Rowwise: 37.96852993965149
```

2) Bit more items:

```
N_USERS = 3000
N_ITEMS = 100
a = np.random.choice(2,(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
b = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    mean_aps(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Original:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_colwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Colwise:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_rowwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Rowwise:',end-start)
```

Out:

```
Original: 14.943019151687622
Colwise: 2.0997579097747803
Rowwise: 11.798128604888916
```

3) Lots of items:

```
N_USERS = 3000
N_ITEMS = 1000
a = np.random.choice(2,(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
b = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    mean_aps(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Original:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_colwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Colwise:',end-start)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    avg_prec_rowwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Rowwise:',end-start)
```

Out:

```
Original: 20.760642051696777
Colwise: 248.5634708404541
Rowwise: 17.940539121627808
```

4) Last comparison between original and rowwise, without any loops:

```
N_USERS = 10000
N_ITEMS = 1000
a = np.random.choice(2,(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
b = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))

start = time.time()
mean_aps(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Original:',end-start)

start = time.time()
avg_prec_rowwise(a,b)
end = time.time()
print('Rowwise:',end-start)
```

Out:

```
Original: 6.912739515304565
Rowwise: 5.9845476150512695
```

Comment: Wow, you seem like a numpy wizard! Your custom function does give identical results to `mean_aps` but unfortunately it scales very poorly. For 3000 users & 1000 items, it takes ~50 times that of `mean_aps`. For 10000 users, it kills my jupyter.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it scales badly. After thresholding, yp becomes an array of size 1000x3000x1000, which is too large.

Comment: @kamalbanga I edited in three different implementations. The noloop function shows that it is possible to do this without any loops, but it'll make your jupyter crash. colwise won't make your jupyter crash, but scales poorly to items; it's really fast when items<=100. Lastly, rowwise is similar to mean_aps, but it is always 10-20% faster, which is the best that can be done, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have much insight on the question, until you provided your own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988865/5218354).

I assume that the code there is performing the correct operation.
I also assume that `k` is typically much smaller than the number of scores.
If that is the case, you can optimize your code quite a bit because you do not need to sort as much as you do, you are only interested in the largest `k` values being sorted when performing the computation of `actual`.
To do that you can use [`np.argpartition()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html#numpy.argpartition).
Also, the indexing you perform after your `np.argsort()` call is quite cumbersome.
A cleaner approach is with the use of [`np.take_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis).
The following code implements all this.

```
import numpy as np


def dcg_score_opt_np(values, scores, k):
    idx = np.argsort(scores, axis=1)[:, :-k - 1:-1]
    values = np.take_along_axis(values, idx, 1)
    result = np.sum(values / np.log2(2 + np.arange(values.shape[1])), axis=1)
    return result


def ndcg_score_opt_np(y_true, y_score, k):
    best = dcg_score_opt_np(y_true, y_true, k)
    n = y_score.shape[1]
    if n > k:
        idx = np.argpartition(y_score, n - k, axis=1)[:, -k:]
        y_true = np.take_along_axis(y_true, idx, 1)
        y_score = np.take_along_axis(y_score, idx, 1)
    actual = dcg_score_opt_np(y_true, y_score, k)
    return actual / best
```

---

Also the computation of `best` is independent of `y_score` and could be computed more efficiently if one notices that the only relevant quantity is the number of `1`s in `y_true`.
Unfortunately, the subsequent computation cannot be done efficiently in NumPy.
But if you are willing to use Numba, you could write:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def dcg(scores):
    result = 0
    for i, score in enumerate(scores, 2):
        if score > 0.0:
            result += score / np.log2(i)
    return result


@nb.jit
def idcg(n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(2, n + 2):
        result += 1 / np.log2(i)
    return result


@nb.jit
def dcg_score(result, scores, k):
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        result[i] = dcg(scores[i, :k])


@nb.jit
def idcg_score(result, counts, k):
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
        n = counts[i] if counts[i] < k else k
        result[i] = idcg(n)


def idcg_score_opt_nb(values, k):
    counts = np.count_nonzero(values, axis=1)
    result = np.empty(values.shape[0])
    idcg_score(result, counts, k)
    return result


def dcg_score_opt_nb(values, scores, k):
    idx = np.argsort(scores, axis=1)[:, :-k - 1:-1]
    values = np.take_along_axis(values, idx, 1)
    result = np.empty(scores.shape[0])
    dcg_score(result, values, k)
    return result


def ndcg_score_opt_nb(y_true, y_score, k):
    best = idcg_score_opt_nb(y_true, k)
    n = y_score.shape[1]
    if n > k:
        idx = np.argpartition(y_score, n - k, axis=1)[:, -k:]
        y_true = np.take_along_axis(y_true, idx, 1)
        y_score = np.take_along_axis(y_score, idx, 1)
    actual = dcg_score_opt_nb(y_true, y_score, k)
    return actual / best
```

Note that `dcg_score_opt_nb()` is not really necessary and it seems to be substantially on par with `dcg_score_opt_np()`.
The additional advantage of Numba-enhanced implementations is that they are more memory efficient as the use of temporary arrays is kept to a minimum.

---

A simple test to show that we are getting the same results all along gives:

```
N_USERS = 6
N_ITEMS = 4
k = 3
np.random.seed(0)
y_true = np.random.choice(2, (N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
y_score = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
print(ndcg_score_2d(y_true, y_score, k))
# [0.61314719 1.         0.76536064 0.63092975 1.         0.38685281]
print(ndcg_score_opt_np(y_true, y_score, k))
# [0.61314719 1.         0.76536064 0.63092975 1.         0.38685281]
print(ndcg_score_opt_nb(y_true, y_score, k))
# [0.61314719 1.         0.76536064 0.63092975 1.         0.38685281]
```

While a benchmark on a respectable dataset gives:

```
N_USERS = 3000
N_ITEMS = 2000
k = 100
y_true = np.random.choice(2, (N_USERS, N_ITEMS))
y_score = np.random.random(size=(N_USERS, N_ITEMS))

%timeit ndcg_score_2d(y_true, y_score, k)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 540 ms per loop
%timeit ndcg_score_opt_np(y_true, y_score, k)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 226 ms per loop
%timeit ndcg_score_opt_nb(y_true, y_score, k)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop
```

Comment: The suggestion for `np.argpartition` is awesome! `ndcg_score_opt_np` works identically to the above presented `ndcg_score_2d` and takes about half time. Thanks for the wonderful idea :)
However, the _numba_ based `ndcg_score_opt_nb` seems to give wrong results as per my testing.

Comment: @kamalbanga Can you narrow down where the problem is? If it is in `dcg_score_opt_nb()`, perhaps you can just use `dcg_score_opt_np()`, since the main reason to use Numba is to compute `idcg_score()`. In any case, can you provide an example where the Numba code fails?

Comment: I realised I made a dumb mistake: I said `true_scores` is binary, which was necessary for `average_precision` but since it isn't necessary for `ndcg`, I was taking a non-binary `true_scores` where the true score is _relevance_ of the user on that item. Maybe that's the reason, `ndcg_score_2d` and `ndcg_score_opt_np` are aligned while `ndcg_score_opt_nb` isn't (for my data).

Comment: @kamalbanga Indeed  `idcg_score_opt_nb()` assumes a binary true score. If that is no longer the case, then the Numba version does not indeed provide any meaningful speed advantage, but with the proper fixes (i.e. using `dcg_score_opt_nb()` instead of `idcg_score_opt_nb()`) should have a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this for *NDCG* score (linear relevance). Code is extended for 2D version similar [to the code here](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/7337391).

```
import numpy as np

def dcg_score_2d(y_true, y_score, k=100):
    order = np.argsort(y_score)[:, ::-1]
    y_true = y_true[np.arange(y_true.shape[0])[:,np.newaxis], order[:, :k]]
    discounts = np.log2(np.arange(y_true.shape[-1]) + 2)
    return np.sum(y_true / discounts, axis=1)

def ndcg_score_2d(y_true, y_score, k=100):
    best = dcg_score_2d(y_true, y_true, k=k)
    actual = dcg_score_2d(y_true, y_score, k=k)
    return actual / best
```

Although it didn't yield me much performance gains over the `for` loop as I was expecting.